# ExtJS: How do I reorder accordion layout panels?

Tags: extjs, panel, accordion

ExtJS: How do I reorder accordion layout panels?

I want to be able to drag and drop the each sub panel in the accordion layout to reorder them just like the below image which does it with table columns...

[image]

Comment: Could you give more information about what you're trying to do? I don't understand what you mean by "I want to do sth".

Comment: I have included more information. Sorry, I thought the pic would be clear enough.

Comment: Just like in any other layout - you must implement DnD. There is plenty of examples on ExtJS site.